# .NET: Animation common control for .NET?

Tags: .net, winapi

Did Microsoft not provide a managed wrapper around the [Animation common control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761884.aspx) for .NET developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can get it [here.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/CGAnimation.aspx)

Comment: Beware the solution linked to doesn't work in Windows 7 Beta.

Comment: Is the Animation common control removed in Windows 7? Or does the random code that someone found on the internet not work?